# Does the Ramanujan-Petersson condition correspond to a Fourier type property?

Tags: nt.number-theory, automorphic-forms, fourier-transform, schwartz-distributions, selberg-class

The Ramanujan-Petersson is one of the requirements used in Selberg's class of L-functions, and as such is a necessary condition for the Riemann Hypothesis to hold. The general converse conjecture posits that this class of L-functions coincides with the class of L-functions associated to automorphic forms, where in this realm the Ramanujan conjecture translates as the Satake parameters at unramified places being of modulus $1$. That way, this property is preserved under the Rankin-Selberg convolution provided it is well-defined. This evokes a distributional aspect of those L-functions, namely that the convolution of any two thereof exists and "lies in the same space".

On the other hand, the Fourier transform swaps multiplication and convolution, and can be proven to be an automorphism of the Schwartz class.

So I would like to know if the Ramanujan-Petersson condition corresponds to a Fourier-like aspect of the Dirichlet coefficients of an L-function of the Selberg class, on which the Fourier transform could act as an inner symmetry. I would also be interested in insights about a possible link to Booker's view of "L-functions as distributions".